# Using Ubuntu's subsystem on Windows for 'make' gives java error

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu, java-8

I am trying to execute Makefile as part of my course. It's a parser and lexer in CUP and Jflex, respectively. It is not possible to do it in Windows Powershell, so I was advised to use Linux, my colleague was also able to run it on Ubuntu's subsystem on Windows.

So I downloaded the ubuntu:

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab
> from MS Store

Then allowed to use Linux subsystem in the Windows settings, however now, when I try to run
`make` in bash, I get this error:

```
mkdir -p bin
java -jar lib/jflex-1.8.2.jar -d src/ src/Lexer.lex
make: java: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:10: bin/SC.class] Error 127
```

Do you know why is that? My colleague did this on desktop, and apprently after doing make for the first
time, the bash asked him whether he wanted to have JDK 8 installed, and after the bash installed it, it worked. But now, when he is trying to do it on his windows laptop, he has the same problem as me. Also note, that I have JDK 15 installed on my machine

Comment: WSL doesn't know about any software you installed on Windows. I think it would be easiest to install it again for the subsystem using `apt install ...`. Alternatively, you can use Windows' java.exe from inside WSL, see https://superuser.com/q/1216231/652023

Comment: that's exactly what I thought, my colleague tried to convince me that WSL would however operate on my Windows, so it should be able to see all the apps and programs installed, including the JDK, so would https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-ubuntu-18-04/ work?

Comment: like installing java8 this way : `sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run all the Windows 10 executables including Java from within WSL, but note that GNU/Linux won't tack on ".EXE" by default as Windows does (Windows uses `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT ...` for this purpose), and WSL won't necessarily have the Windows binaries on the bash PATH.

For example my installation of JDK14 is at Windows `C:\java\jdk-14` == WSL `/mnt/c/java/jdk-14`:

```
 /mnt/c/java/jdk-14/bin/java -version
 => Fails with 
 bash: /mnt/c/java/jdk-14/bin/java: No such file or directory
 /mnt/c/java/jdk-14/bin/java.exe -version
 java version "14" 2020-03-17
```

You can fix your makefile / run issue with one or more of the following:

1. Try setting your WSL bash PATH to contain the Windows JDK and edit your makefile command to `java.exe` not `java`

   ```
     export PATH=/mnt/c/java/jdk-14/bin:$PATH
     java.exe -version
     => Should work
   ```
2. Alternatively symbolic link `java` to `java.exe` - assuming PATH contains `.`

   ```
     export PATH=.:$PATH
     ln -s /mnt/c/java/jdk-14/bin/java.exe java
     java -version
     => Should work
   ```
3. Install Java on WSL - the link suggested by @Samuel V. would work, although if you want specific JDK it is easier to download a [reference Linux release](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/15).